# Unable to retrieve AUTH_TOKEN from header in HTTP request

Tags: django, http-headers, django-rest-framework

I have a HTTP request where i save the "AUTH_TOKEN" key as header key-value.
This i try and retrieve using 
request.META.get('HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN').
The token value is correctly fetched in my localhost requests, but post migration to the staging server, the token value is never recognised. 
I'm lost here, since the code is the same. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **Apache**, you may be running into the fact that Apache removes the authorization header, whereas the development server doesn't.  I'm not sure if Nginx does something similar.

Try adding `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to your `.conf` file in Apache.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache with something like `apache2ctl graceful`.

Comment: It was the underscore in key "AUTH_TOKEN" creating the problem. I changed the header key to plain "TOKEN" and it seems to work fine.